# A recurrence relation problem from the eigenvalue of a special tridiagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $a,b$ are real numbers greater than $k\geq 1$. Consider the polynomial sequence $D_{0}(\lambda),D_{1}(\lambda),\ldots,D_{k}(\lambda)$ satisfying the following recurrence relation:
\begin{align*}
D_t(\lambda) &= \left[(a-t)(b-k+t) + t(k-t+1)-\lambda\right] \cdot D_{t-1}(\lambda) \\
&\quad - (a-t+1)(b-k+t-1)t(k-t+1)\cdot D_{t-2}(\lambda) 
\end{align*}
for $t=0,1,\ldots,k$ , with first two terms $D_{-2}=D_{-1}=1$.

How to prove the following equation?
\begin{equation*}
D_k(\lambda) = \prod_{t=0}^k \left[ (a-t)(b-t)-\lambda \right]
\end{equation*}

p.s. This question originates from Eq.(19) in [element distinctness revisited](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.11336) . It is about eigenvalues of a special reduced staggered quantum walk operator $U:=(2BB^T-I)(2AA^T-I)$ on a quasi Johnson graph.  The operator $U$ 's eigenvalues can be derived from the singular values of $A^T B$ (by Corollary 3.5 in [The spectra of the unitary matrix of a 2-tessellable staggered quantum walk on a graph](https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.08274v1)), so it is left to determine the spectra of the tridiagonal matrix $C:=A^T B B^T A$. After some transformation (a:=r+1, b:=N-r and multiply $C$ by $ab$ ), and expanding $|C-\lambda I|$ leads to the question posted here. The tridiagonal matrix $C$ is shown in the following:

\begin{matrix}
(a-k)b +k\cdot1 & \sqrt{(a-(k-1))(b-1)\ k\cdot1} & & &\\
\sqrt{(a-(k-1))(b-1)\ k\cdot1} & (a-(k-1))(b-1)+ (k-1)\cdot2 & \sqrt{(a-(k-2))(b-2)\ (k-1)\cdot2} & &\\
 & \sqrt{(a-(k-2))(b-2)\ (k-1)\cdot2} & \ddots & \ddots & \\
 &  &\ddots & \ddots & \sqrt{a(b-k)\ 1\cdot k} \\
 &  &  & \sqrt{a(b-k)\ 1\cdot k} & a(b-k)+0\cdot(k+1)
\end{matrix}

[image: matrix C]

The eigenvalues of the above quantum walk operator $U$ is first considered in [Quantum walk algorithm for element distinctness](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0311001v9) , but only a bound was given (Lemma 2). The closed form was given by Eq.(19) in [element distinctness revisited](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.11336) but lack explicit proof. I've sent an email to the author on this matter, but have received no reply yet.